# How to get the exact value of $\sin(x)$ if $\sin(2x) = \frac{24}{25}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to get the exact value of $\sin(x)$ if $\sin(2x) = \frac{24}{25}$ ?

I checked various trigonometric identities, but I am unable to derive $\sin(x)$ based on the given information.

For instance:
$\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$

Comment: $4sin^2 cos^2 = (24/25)^2$, $ cos^2 =1 - sin^2 $, solve the previous for $sin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos ^2 {2x} = 1-\sin ^2 {2x} = \frac {49}{625}$$
$$ \cos 2x = \frac {7}{25}$$
$$ \sin ^ 2x = \frac {1-\cos 2x}{2} = 9/25 $$
$$ \sin x =  \frac {3}{5} $$

Comment: Check the case of $\frac{-3}{5}$. If $\sin(x)=\frac{-3}{5}$, then $\sin(2x)=-\frac{24}{25}$

Comment: @RhysHughes  Good comment, thanks,

Comment: In your first line, you should have $\cos^2(2x) = 1 - \sin^2(2x) = \frac{49}{625}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: That covers only one of four solutions due to two $y^2=z^2\to y=z$ fallacies.

Comment: yes, there are other solutions as well. $\pm 3/5, \pm 4/5$ are also solutions. As long as $\sin 2x = \frac {24}{25}$ any of those four solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos 2x=\pm\frac{7}{25}$, $\tan x=\frac{\sin 2x}{1+\cos 2x}\in\left\{\frac{24}{32},\,\frac{24}{18}\right\}=\left\{\frac{3}{4},\,\frac{4}{3}\right\}$ so $\sin x=\pm\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}}\in\pm\left\{\frac{3}{5},\,\frac{4}{5}\right\}=\left\{-\frac{4}{5},\,-\frac{3}{5},\,\frac{3}{5},\,\frac{4}{5}\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\sin(2x)|=|2\sin(x)\cos(x)|=|2\sin(x)\sqrt{1-\sin(x)^2}|$$
so
$$\left(\frac{24}{25}\right)^2=4\sin(x)^2(1-\sin(x)^2)$$
solve this quadratic for $\sin(x)^2$ and get $|\sin(x)|$. Both the positive and negative values will be possible (think of why).

Comment: Square should be inside paranthesis not outside..

Answer (score 1):

$tanx=\frac{sin2x}{1+cos2x}$. You have $\sin2x$ and you can calculate $\cos2x$ with the Pythagorean theorem. Once you have $\ tanx$, you can use SOHCAHTOA. Don't forget the quadrants though

Comment: Use a backslash before trig functions like `\sin x` so they render as $\sin x$ and not $sin x$

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the diagram below.

$AD$ is the angle bisector of the right-angled triangle $\Delta ABC$.

Given $BC=24$ and $AC=25$.

Let $\angle DAB = x$.

From $\Delta ABC$ we see that $\sin(2x) = \dfrac{24}{25}$.

Now, by [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), $BD:DC = 7:25$.

Therefore, $BD = \dfrac{7}{7+25} \times 24 = \dfrac{21}4$.

Observing that $AB:BD = 4:3$, we see that $AD = \dfrac{35}4$

Therefore, $\sin x = \dfrac {BD} {DA} = \dfrac 3 5$.

The other possible $x$ would be $x+180^\circ$, since the period of sine is $360^\circ$, making $\sin x = -\dfrac35$.

In conclusion, $\sin x = \pm \dfrac 35$.

[image]

Comment: Be careful $\sin^{-1}(-\frac 35)\approx -0.6435$ then $\sin(2\cdot-0.6435)=-\frac{24}{25}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(2x)=\frac{24}{25}$$
The identities you want are:
$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x) \space [I]$$

and
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1\space[II]$$

Square $[I]$ to get:
$$4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=\frac{576}{625}\to\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)=\frac{144}{625}$$
$$\to\sin^4(x)-\sin^2x+\frac{144}{625}=0$$
Let $\sin^2(x)=\sigma$. Your equation becomes:
$\sigma^2-\sigma+\frac{144}{625}=0$

Solve via Quadratic Formula:
$$\sigma=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{576}{625}}}{2}=\frac 12\pm\frac{\sqrt{\frac{49}{625}}}{2}=\frac{9}{25}, \frac{16}{25}.$$

Since $\sin^2(x)=\frac{9}{25}, \frac{16}{25}, \sin(x)=\pm \frac 35, \pm \frac 45$

Check these values with the function $f(S)=\sin(2\cdot\sin^{-1}(S))$, (where $S$ is the solutions i.e. $\pm\frac 35, \pm \frac 45$) to see the ones which provide the correct solution, and note the values which work are $\frac 35, \frac 45$.

We can see them graphed [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kaeekwrhmp):